# How to get a USB device path by its idVendor and idProduct?

Tags: linux, usb, c++, usb-device

Now I can get a USB device's idVendor and idProduct. How to use them to get its path like `/dev/ttyACM0` or `/dev/ttyUSB0`? The next function needs this path instead of its idVendor and idProduct.

Notice: by Coding, not by Command.

Comment: What do you mean by “by Coding, not by Command”? If you mean you're writing a program, you're on the wrong site. This site is for users and administrators, programming questions are off-topic. If you're writing a program, you need to edit your question to say in what language, and flag your question for migration.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding. I will change to another site.

Answer (score 1):

You usually do it the other way round: write a specific `udev` rule for a particular vendor/product that creates a known symlink you can use in your "next function". Google for lots of tutorials how such a rule looks like.

Or you write your application in such a way that you can pass the path to the device as an argument.

It's possible to walk the device path in `/sys/devices` backwards and check at each step if this is an usb device and has a particular vendor/product. That's what e.g. `udevadm info -a /dev/ttyUSB0` does. You need to do it that way, because it need not be a USB device, it could be anything.

If you *have* to do it "by coding, not by command", look at the source of `udevadm` and copy whatever it does. This will be a non-trivial effort, and it can't be simplified a lot, so I really suggest to do it differently.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try libudev and see if it works.